# Assert is seen as C style cast in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings, assert, cpp-core-guidelines

[Here is the error and a glimpse of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5Eoc.png) One of my courses demands me to use Warning Level 4 and to treat warnings as errors in Visual Studio. Beside that, we also need to activate Cpp Core Guidelines. However, since I activated these options I've been haunted by warning error C26493 (don't use C style casts). Apparently, they consider my "assert" tests as C style casts. I haven't seen any other student having this problem. Can somebody help me fix this thing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] which causes the error, and also copy-paste (as text) the full and complete build output into the question. And add a comment on the line where you get the error.

Comment: Also, it's probably not something you can do about it, since the cast is inside the `assert` macro itself. So for you it's a false positive.

Comment: Finally, don't use `assert` as a run-time validation check. It doesn't do anything for "release" builds, and for debug builds it "crashes" the program if the assertion fails (which is a rather bad experience for a user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assert is a macro that expands (in visual studio) to:

```cpp
    #define assert(expression) (void)(                                                       \
            (!!(expression)) ||                                                              \
            (_wassert(_CRT_WIDE(#expression), _CRT_WIDE(__FILE__), (unsigned)(__LINE__)), 0) \
        )
```

As you can see, there is a C-style case to void.

Comment: And there is no other tool like assert to make tests?

Answer (score 1):

All students should see the warning, not just you. If you want to avoid this warning, use an implementation of ASSERT using C++-style casts.

Any standard ASSERT macro I've been working with expands to a C-style cast to void but a gcc c++ mode: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/assert/assert.h

Here is an example of my custom implementation using C++ casts. This is also using a global variable in debug mode to be able to disable assertions while debugging.

```
extern MYUTILS_DLLINTERFACE bool g_MYASSERT_enabled;
extern bool MYUTILS_DLLINTERFACE _is_MYASSERT_enabled();
#ifdef _DEBUG
# define __MYASSERT(x) (static_cast<void>(!_is_MYASSERT_enabled() || (_ASSERTE(x), 0)))
#else
# define __MYASSERT(x) (static_cast<void>(0))
#endif
```